# Who is being spoken to in the BSG miniseries?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, battlestar-galactica-2004

Just started rewatching Battlestar Galactica. In the 
miniseries, shortly before the bombing of Caprica, Six turns and addresses someone off-camera "About time you got here."

Is it ever revealed who she was speaking to?

Comment: SPOILERS if you have seen the main series yet!!!! I think it was “Angel” Baltaar.......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We finally get to see who she was speaking to in [*BSG: The Plan*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battlestar_Galactica:_The_Plan). It was a Cavil, advising her that the attack on Caprica was imminent.

> **Six:** *It's about time. I wondered when you'd get here.*
>
> **Cavil:** *Are you clear on the timing?*
>
> **Six:** *0700 tomorrow, Caprica City Time.*
>
> **Cavil:** *I'd recommend you leave this body behind. The alternative won't make for a very pleasant memory. Oh, and I hear that poison really isn't all that bad.*

[image]

Comment: Thank you - only watched The Plan once and had entirely forgotten that was in it.

Comment: @Michael - I'd totally forgotten it too. Had to rewatch it